# Generating random numbers from a piecewise probability distrubution in matlab

Tags: matlab

I am trying to input the following piecewise function into matlab as a probability distribution. Then I'm trying to generate random values of X. I have the statistic tool box so I can generate the random numbers using that, but I cannot figure out how to input the function so that I can actually generate the random numbers.

```
P(X)= Ax 0<=x<1
      A/2 1<=x<2
      0 otherwise
```

A is a normalization constant.

I ultimately want to show a histogram of 10,000 trials from this distribution and find the mean and standard deviation of my simulation.

Answer (score 2):

samples from given distribution can be generated for instance using inverse transform sampling (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling) It's quite easy since you just generate uniformly distributed values and then compute inverse of your cumulative distribuition function

Cumulative distrib. function can be computed by integration of propability density function, in your case

x^2/2 ... x  from <0,1>

x/2 ... x from (1,2>

Note, that the normalizing constant is A=1
now, the m-file doing this  is the following

```
function vals =genDist(len)
vals =  rand(len,1);
for i=1:length(vals)
    if vals(i)<=1/2 % vals(i) 0..0.5
        vals(i) = sqrt(2*vals(i));%inverse function of x^2/2 
    else % vals(i) 0.5-1
        vals(i) = vals(i)*2; %inverse function of x/2
    end
end
```

end

Comment: Thank you for responding! That makes sense but what exactly is "len" in this case?

Comment: Also matlab is not recognizing genDist as a function...do I need a different took box for that?

Comment: len is the number of samples, the function must be located somewhere in your matlab path to be recognized (for instance in current folder)